# how to update a product price in web api using C#

Tags: c#

```
public async Task<GlobalResponse> UpdateProductPrice(UpdateProductPrice model)
{
    var product = await _db.ProductAndServices.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == model.ProductId);
    if (product == null)
    {
        return new GlobalResponse { Status = false, Message = "Product not found" };
    }
      
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return new GlobalResponse { Status = true, Message = "Product updated" };
}
```

Comment: This question is fairly low quality, take a look at [ask], also this sort of question (which is at the lower end of usefulness for this site), should be directed at your instructor or teacher

Comment: This will depend on how your web pages are supplied with data. You only show an update to a database. Where's the API to retrieve it? We can't help you because this will depend on what framework and technologies your project is using. As noted by @TheGeneral your question is too generic. Please bear in mind that this forum is not a free programming service. Post up something that you have tried, which may have some specific error that we can help you with.

Comment: @ChrisBD _"You only show an update to a database."_ - Actually, not even that. The entity is not altered anywhere. So, `SaveChangesAsync` shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: @Chuks: You'd need to set `product` - price property to `model`'s price proterty value and then call update for a change to take effect.

Comment: https://entityframeworkcore.com/saving-data-savechangesasync here is an example how you van add something, it is somewhat same with updating I believe. (I am more of a dapper user, not e.f.)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UpdateProductPrice 
{
int Id {get;set;}
decimal Price {get;set;}
}
public async Task<GlobalResponse> UpdateProductPrice(UpdateProductPrice model)
{
    var product = await _db.ProductAndServices.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == model.ProductId);
    if (product == null)
    {
        return new GlobalResponse { Status = false, Message = "Product not found" };
    }
    product.Price= model.Price; 
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return new GlobalResponse { Status = true, Message = "Product updated" };
}
```

I hope, it will be resolved your problem.